# How do I configure Textmate2 to always show wrap Column line for all files?

Tags: textmate

I want to show the wrap column line for all files, how can I do this? I checked the `.tm_properties` file, but I don't see any mention of it in there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind.

`showWrapColumn    = true` fixed it.